Load xml files to a df (to many levels)
I am trying to load data from many xml files with etree.ElementTree.
The data in the xml looks like this sample:
<mydata>
<Record>
   <Field name="ParaA">2927695</Field>
   <Field name="Index"/>
   <Field name="ParaB">D:\path\data</Field>
   <Field name="ParaC">116.4</Field>
   <Field name="ParaD">1583.4</Field>
   <Field name="ParaBE">12.0</Field>
   <Row>
      <Field name="Para1">1</Field>
      <Field name="Para2">D5A</Field>
      <Field name="Para3">1586.0</Field>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <Field name="Para1">2</Field>
      <Field name="Para2">D4A</Field>
      <Field name="Para3">118.0</Field>
      <Field name="Para4">12.0</Field>
   </Row>
   </Record>
   </mydata>

The number of row is dynamic. I want do get a df with
ParaA | Para1 | Para2
Already read the documentation but was not able to solve it. I think the problem is that row is under record.
What I need is a df like this below
ParaA    Para1 Para2 Para3   Para4
2927695  1     D5A   1586.0
2927695  2     D4A   118.0   12.0

The df with my code is empty
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml_file = r'.\Test.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()


data = []


for record in root.findall('record'):
    record_data = {}
    for elem in record:
        record_data[elem.tag] = elem.text
    data.append(record_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

Hope someone can help.

it is not clear what your problem is. please provide: your code, your result and your expected result

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

I don't remember if module xml converts names to lower case - so I would expect that it has to be Record with upper R instead of record

did you try pandas.read_xml()

works with the data you provided
for record in root.findall('Record'):
    record_data = []
    for elem in record:
        match elem.tag:
            case 'Field':
                if elem.attrib['name'] == 'ParaA':
                    paraa = elem.text
            case 'Row':
                row={'ParaA': paraa}
                for field in elem.findall('Field'):
                    row.update({field.attrib['name']:field.text})
                record_data.append(row)

df output:
     ParaA Para1 Para2   Para3 Para4
0  2927695     1   D5A  1586.0   NaN
1  2927695     2   D4A   118.0  12.0

